# How do I disable automatic equation numbering when using MathJax in GitHub Markdown files?

Tags: github, latex, markdown

The title is pretty much the question.

I enjoy using LaTeX when writing in Markdown files on GitHub, but I noticed when I use `$$ something $$` the file automatically numbers the equation. How do I stop this from happening?

Thanks.